# Xcode search paths not working

Tags: xcode

So, I need to import the header files of a framework I am including in my library.

I have gone to Target -> General -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries and imported/references my frameworks there.

Also, I have populated the various search path fields in project settings.

My problem is that none of those work.

The only thing that works is by specifying an absolute path to the header file in the code file as below:

```
</Users/bob/Repositories/sdk-ios/Products/SDK.framework/Headers/SDK.h>
```

Obviously, this is a non runner - how can I get the regular search methods to work.

Thanks.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/IncludingFrameworks.html) you shouldn't have to mess with the *Header Search Path* at all.  Just use the conventional `#import <FrameworkName/FrameworkName.h>`.

Comment: Well to be honest, that's not working.

Comment: No, he needs to add the Framework first, then include in source code.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not 3rd party framework then don't mess by writing paths in config.

Just select your app target -> goto General -> scroll down here:
[image]

and add the Framework.

PS: if still wish to configure, dont use absolute paths. Use "${PROJECT_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AFNetworking"